# Running WPS to work with WRF (weather forecasting System )

Tags: weather

I am running WPS, to work with WRF(Weather Forecasting Model), but I find a problem in running WPS, which is:

At line 143 of file gridinfo_module.f90 (unit = 10, file = 'namelist.wps')
Fortran runtime error: Invalid string input in item 14

```
Error termination. Backtrace:
#0  0x7fd2b51a2ef7 in ???
#1  0x7fd2b51a3a95 in ???
#2  0x7fd2b51a424c in ???
#3  0x7fd2b526988f in ???
#4  0x7fd2b5269d0b in ???
#5  0x7fd2b526bf39 in ???
#6  0x7fd2b527365d in ???
#7  0x7fd2b5273848 in ???
#8  0x404a0b in ???
#9  0x40334c in ???
#10  0x7fd2b4ad482f in ???
#11  0x402428 in ???
#12  0xffffffffffffffff in ???
```

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this problem, or someone who has already met it?
Thank you very much.

**I am following that exists here: http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/OnLineTutorial/compilation_tutorial.php

Answer (score 1):

This error means you need to double-check your namelist.wps.  Apparently, line 14 is problematic.  It could either be a bad key or a bad value it is complaining about.  The error message seems to indicate that the value should be a string. It is hard to know what the problem is without seeing your namelist.wps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem which was due to **Windows line endings (EOL)**. WRF and WPS were running in a Linux Docker container where a Windows volume was mounted. If the file was edited with a Windows IDE, **CR/LF line endings were in it**. So I soved it with `dos2unix` inside the docker container after the file was imported to the docker container.